# writing code blocks in my html

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to archive this in my html:

[image]

jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/cr9vkc7f/4/

I tried as you see insert the border in the left of my code

```
 border-left: 1px solid #444;
```

what I have right now is that but I want move the numbers to left side to be equal my first pic:
[image]

someone can help me with that, I really sure I am very close to archive it.

Comment: Like this https://jsfiddle.net/j08691/2nn81hda/?

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.   Although you have provided a [**link to an example or site**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it), if the link were to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem.

Comment: @Paulie_D the jsfiddle is not enough?

Comment: Nope...what if JSFiddle breaks or does down? Then your code is inaccessible. That why it's a requirement for questions  seeking code help to include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).

Answer (score 0):

You have to render the empty lines:

```
    <ol class="linenums">
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
      <li class=""><code><span class="tag">&lt;pre&gt;</span><span class="pln">&amp;lt;p&amp;gt;A block of code is wrapped in pre tags&amp;lt;/p&amp;gt;</span><span class="tag">&lt;/pre&gt;</span></code></li>
      <li class=""><code><span class="tag">&lt;p&gt;</span><span class="pln">For example, </span><span class="tag">&lt;code&gt;</span><span class="pln">&amp;lt;section&amp;gt;</span><span class="tag">&lt;/code&gt;</span><span class="pln"> should be wrapped as inline.</span><span class="tag">&lt;/p&gt;</span></code></li>
      <li class=""><code><span class="tag">&lt;p&gt;</span><span class="pln">To switch directories, type </span><span class="tag">&lt;kbd&gt;</span><span class="pln">cd</span><span class="tag">&lt;/kbd&gt;</span><span class="pln"> followed by the name of the directory.</span><span class="tag">&lt;/p&gt;</span></code></li>
    </ol>
```

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by 'did not work'. What was the output, and what were you expecting? This should work fine...

Comment: sorry but this is not I want, I attached a pic when I created the question is the first image, what I want archie is this: http://i.stack.imgur.com/2LEQO.png

Comment: do you mean the space between the lines?

Comment: @JeroenDop yes, having the numbers in the left and that line dividing code and numbers exactly what you are seeing in the image :)

Comment: @Raduken Lee's comment is *completely* fine. It's an absolutely normal thing to ask for clarification when you give a vague statement like "did not work". You need to be much clearer in your description of your problems, and less quick to assume some kind of offence is intended when people ask you to add details.

Answer (score 0):

https://jsfiddle.net/cr9vkc7f/5/

```css
.panel-code.pre {
  border-radius: .5em;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;

  overflow-x: scroll;
  padding: .5em .3em;
}

ol.linenums {
  border-left: 1px solid #444;
  margin: 0 0 0 3.3em;
  background-color: #333;
  /* IE indents via margin-left */
  padding: 0;
}

ol.linenums li {
  line-height: 1.5;
  padding-left: .8em;
  list-style: decimal inside;
  
  display: list-item;
}
.tag {
    
}
```

```html
<div class="panel-body panel-code" ng-show="isShow" ng-click="changeValue(false)">

  <code>        <ol class="linenums">
          <li class=""><code><span class="tag">&lt;pre&gt;</span><span class="pln">&amp;lt;p&amp;gt;A block of code is wrapped in pre tags&amp;lt;/p&amp;gt;</span><span class="tag">&lt;/pre&gt;</span></code></li>
          <li class=""><code><span class="tag">&lt;p&gt;</span><span class="pln">For example, </span><span class="tag">&lt;code&gt;</span><span class="pln">&amp;lt;section&amp;gt;</span><span class="tag">&lt;/code&gt;</span><span class="pln"> should be wrapped as inline.</span><span class="tag">&lt;/p&gt;</span></code></li>
          <li class=""><code><span class="tag">&lt;p&gt;</span><span class="pln">To switch directories, type </span><span class="tag">&lt;kbd&gt;</span><span class="pln">cd</span><span class="tag">&lt;/kbd&gt;</span><span class="pln"> followed by the name of the directory.</span><span class="tag">&lt;/p&gt;</span></code></li>
        </ol>
      </code>

  
</div>
```

Comment: sorry but this is not I want, I attached a pic when I created the question is the first image, what I want archie is this: http://i.stack.imgur.com/2LEQO.png